# Prevent theme styles from loading in custom page template

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website with a theme.
To implement some changes I created a child theme. That works fine.

Now I want to add a page template that allows me to enqueue styles via `wp_enqueue_style`. For that to work I need to add `wp_head()` to my page template if I understand it correctly.

I want to use this custom page template for a front end app that I am creating (plugin).
The design of this app is completely separate from the rest of the website. Right now I get all the theme styles too when I use `wp_head()`. I would like to prevent the default theme styles from loading.

What is the most easy way to achieve this? Preferably a theme independent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging in Google and came up with something that does what I want.
After clearing I can add my own styles and scripts.

```
function clear_styles_and_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    global $wp_styles;

    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :

        wp_dequeue_script( $handle );
        wp_deregister_script( $handle );

    endforeach;

    foreach( $wp_styles ->queue as $handle ) :

        wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
        wp_deregister_style( $handle );

    endforeach;

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'clear_styles_and_scripts', 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include a different header.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

**Multiple Headers**

Different header for different pages.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: That part I understand. But as soon as I put `wp_head()` in the header file it renders the theme styles. These I want to get rid of.